# MYSQL + XML: Iterating through and extracting values from XML data stored as blob in MYSQL table

Tags: mysql, xml

Consider a MYSQL table with more than 50M rows. It has 2 columns, id and req_data. id is varchar and req_data is medium blob, which contains xml data. There is only one row for an id. Here is an example of xml data in req_data:

```
<xml_1>
    <req>
        <id>1</id>
        <Type>M</Type>
    </req>
    <Warnings>
        <Warning>
            <Code>101</Code>
            <Source>A</Source>
        </Warning>
        <Warning>
            <Code>104</Code>
            <Source>B</Source>
        </Warning>
        <Warning>
            <Code>102</Code>
            <Source>A</Source>
        </Warning>
        <Warning>
            <Code>110</Code>
            <Source>B</Source>
        </Warning>
    </Warnings>
</xml_1>
```

From above mentioned MYSQL table, I want to extract data in this format:

| id | type | error_code_A | error_code_B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | M | 101 102 | 104 110 |
| 2 | P | 104 105 106 107 108 | 104 |
| 3 | O | 102 | 105 |
| 4 | I | 107 110 | 109 110 |
| 5 | P | 107 108 110 |  |

I tried this query:

```
SELECT o.id, 
CAST(EXTRACTVALUE(o.req_data, '/xml_1/req/Type') AS CHAR(50)) type,
CAST(EXTRACTVALUE(o.req_data,'/xml_1/Warnings/Warning/Source') AS CHAR (50) CHARACTER SET UTF8) Error_Type, 
CAST(EXTRACTVALUE(o.req_data,'/xml_1/Warnings/Warning/Code') AS CHAR (50) CHARACTER SET UTF8) Error_Code 
FROM my_table o;
```

This gives the following output:

| id | type | error_type | error_code |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | M | A A B B | 101 102 104 110 |
| 2 | P | B A A A A A | 104 104 105 106 107 108 |
| 3 | O | A B | 102 105 |
| 4 | I | B A B A | 109 107 110 110 |
| 5 | P | A A A | 107 108 110 |

I need a query which can give expected output for 50M records, without hitting 30 sec DB time out
I am also okay to use python for this output, but I will have to connect python to mysql as well

Comment: Change the timeout instead.  You database could be fragmented.  Or the hard drive you are using is slow and move db to faster hard drive.  Check Event View for memory.  You may be using 100% of the memory.  Or run on a faster computer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use XPath predicates to produce desired output.

**SQL**

```
SELECT o.id, 
    CAST(EXTRACTVALUE(o.req_data, '/xml_1/req/Type') AS CHAR(50)) type,
    CAST(EXTRACTVALUE(o.req_data,'/xml_1/Warnings/Warning[Source="A"]/Code') AS CHAR (50) CHARACTER SET UTF8) error_code_A, 
    CAST(EXTRACTVALUE(o.req_data,'/xml_1/Warnings/Warning[Source="B"]/Code') AS CHAR (50) CHARACTER SET UTF8) error_code_B 
FROM my_table o;
```